# Dataset Locate number within range

Tags: delphi, dataset, delphi-7, locate

I have this dataset with the following data :

| Winner Name | Coupon Start | Coupon End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joshua | 00001 | 00010 |
| Mark | 00011 | 00020 |
| Stephen | 00021 | 00024 |
| Ina | 00025 | 00025 |

I can easily using Locate to find for example the winner for coupon 00011 which is Mark, but how to find the winner for Coupon between (ie 00023 or 00007) using dataset.locate function

Comment: you want to get 3 names if it's a range of coupons? couponstart <= 00007 and 00023 <= couponstart

Comment: you can use https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Filter and https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Filtered and iterate through your dataset if I understand your question correctly

Comment: substitute couponstart with couponend ofc

Comment: how to locate the number between couponstart and couponend, i tried both locate and filter but the result is none.
onfilterrecord i tried :
    Accept := couponstartfield >= 23 AND couponendfield <= 23;
with no result.

Comment: Try your filter like this.  For finding 7, `(7 >= CouponStart) AND (7 <= CouponEnd)`  it's the same for 23 `(23 >= CouponStart) AND (23 <= CouponEnd)`

Comment: thanks its working now, tried couponstart<=7 and couponend>=7 didn't work.
and it actually work with 7 >=couponstart and 7<=couponend, look similar but the result is different.

Comment: I've added an answer, if you could be so kind as to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Locate to find multiple values in they way that you've asked. You can use a filter, an SQL query, or perhaps even SetRange.  This answer will focus on using TDataset's filter, which can be used as part of an SQL query.

You have to focus your filter with the Winning Ticket.

If the winning ticket is 7, then your filter should be:

```
(7 >= CouponStart) AND (7 <= CouponEnd)
```

Same for a winning ticket of 23

```
(23 >= CouponStart) AND (23 <= CouponEnd)
```